# Is there a scene in the “War of the Worlds” movie depicting a man with a suitcase full of money?

Tags: movie, war-of-the-worlds

I think that in a scene in the 1953 version of the *War of the Worlds* movie, there are trucks, crowded with people escaping (but to where?), and a guy with a suitcase full of money offers to pay someone on the truck but is told that money is no good any more. At this point, the suitcase bursts open and indeed no one seems to care, no one is grabbing all the cash that spilled.

Do I have the right film and details? Is there a scene in the *War of the Worlds* movie depicting a man with a suitcase full of money?

I believe a scene like this may have been in the original novel, but something that occurs to me is that during World War II there were many people doing semi-illegal things and the "trope" of a guy with a suitcase full of money might have existed. In my own experience, I heard stories, in those pre-credit card days when there was a lot more cash floating around, of people keeping a fortune at home that they would be afraid to bank due to legal issues.

The reason I mention the World War II trope idea is that this sort of scene may have appeared in other films also. It is even tangentially related to *When Worlds Collide* when the millionaire who funded the space ships is, despite this, deprived of his seat aboard.

Even in real life, the inability to use wealth to escape, for example, the Nazis, actually occurred – one was likely to have the money/diamonds simply confiscated.

Comment: You mean that specific version of a movie of the serialisation by Wells? (which differs from the original source material quite a bit) Or the novelised serialisation? Can you make the question specific, else it's the start of a discussion.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: I mean the 1953 version -- did it have this?

Comment: In countries that have experienced recent financial crises that have triggered capital control measures or runs on banks (e.g. off the top of my head Argentina, Greece, Cyprus), it is absolutely normal for people to have significant amounts of cash stashed in their homes since they do not trust that if they put it into a bank they will be able to get it out again. This is not something that has anything to do with pre-credit card days.

Comment: @terdon: in pre-credit card days absolutely cash was more important. there were 1000 and even 10000 dollar bills in use in usa.

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely, but being from one of the countries named above I can assure you that it isn't exclusive to that era and is very much still a thing today.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Indeed, it's at 1:11:56 in the copy I have.

[image: A screenshot of the aforementioned scene. A very littered street can be seen, with a guy lying on the ground next to an opened briefcase. The exterior case looks dark brown, and the inside is made of soft blue material. Its content is mostly bills of dollars, along with some silver/metallic looking objects which might be jewellery. People seem to be running around without paying attention to the briefcase full of money.]